# Performance of Python data structure: define inside or outside method?

Tags: python, scope, interpreter

I have a method which relies on a few values stored in a dict. Perhaps this is a micro-optimization, but is it better to define the dict inside the method, or outside? or does it really matter?

Example code:

```
_values = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}

def add_1(val):
    return _values[val] + 1
```

Or:

```
def add_1(val):
    _values = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}

    return _values[val] + 1
```

The code would then be imported and used somewhere else (i.e. different file) ~ `from methods import *`.

What is the path taken by the interpreter when trying to find the dict in each case? My understanding is that looking up the dict outside the method's scope is slightly more expensive.

Comment: You could always time the execution

Comment: It's not recommended to do `from methods import *` as it can easily contaminate your existing namespace.  Having said that, if you intend to import and use `_values`, it's probably better to have it in the global.

Comment: @Idlehands. The `_` implies that OP does not want to import it or use it outside the function for which it is intended.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Right, that was a brain fart moment.  I'd say that's all the more reason to not do the ` from ... import *` line then, especially if they're using method 1.

Comment: @Idlehands. Well, the `_` prefix will actually prevent it from being imported with a star import, so not really a problem even then. For the record, I'm in no way disagreeing that star imports are a bad idea exactly for the reason that you stated.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `_` vars not being included with a star import is something I didn't know.  I always do `import module` and in that case I have still have access to the `module._` vars so I just assumed.  Learned something new, many thanks!

Comment: @Idlehands Indeed, thanks for bringing that up! I chose to use the `*` here to hint that the `_*` fields/methods would not be imported in the other file, but only the methods. Still, using `from methods import add_1` would have probably been more concise.

Answer (score 1):

The first version is faster. Each time you call the second version, it's creating a new dictionary from scratch. It's a small additional time, but it is extra time nonetheless:

```
In [20]: v1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}

In [21]: def add_1(val):
    ...:     return v1[val] + 1

In [22]: %timeit add_1('a')
128 ns ± 0.989 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [23]: def add_2(val):
    ...:     v2 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
    ...:     return v2[val] + 1

In [24]: %timeit add_2('b')
206 ns ± 3.15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every normal function object has a reference to the global namespace of the module that defines it. The first option will perform the lookup in that namespace. The dictionary itself will only be created once, when the module is first executed. Since the reference is stored in `add_1.__globals__`, the lookup will work properly even if you only `import methods.add_1` or `from methods import add_1`. Looking up "G(lobal)" in "LEGB" may be marginally slower than "L(ocal)", but I wouldn't expect a huge difference here.

The second option creates a new dictionary object every time the function runs. I would expect this to outweigh any lookup optimizations from holding the reference in the local namespace. The one advantage this approach does offer is that it makes your dictionary effectively immutable.

While I would intuitively expect the first option to run faster, you would have to do a benchmark for this micro-optimization to be sure. I suspect that it has a lot to do with your Python implementation, computer architecture, dictionary size, and a host of other factors.